# Prevent jwplayer video to download from chrome mobile browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, video, html5-video, jwplayer

I am working on jwplayer video and I need to prevent the video from download.
When i double click on mobile chrome browser while video is playing it gives me the download option.
I have study so many articles and blogs posts about this but still could not find any solution.

I don't want to use HLS stream option. Is there any parameter jwplayer use that recognize the authenticated users and play video only for them? or is there any other way to do it.?

Answer (score 0):

If you are worried about the video being copied by authorised users then ultimately there is no way to stop the user downloading it - the video has to get to the device/browser for it to play and it is not hard to get around any URL obfuscating etc.

The usual approach to avoid copying is to encrypt the video and use some secure way to send the key to decrypt it.

This is essentially what DRM systems do.

The stronger DRM implementations generally also make sure that the end user or application never is able to . This is done by having the encrypted video and the key do their work within a 'secure media path' in the device, that applications and even the OS have no access to.