# Is their a way to prevent ts segments of video from Jwplayer to be sniffed?

Tags: video, video-streaming, jwplayer, packet-sniffers

Hi hope you guys are having a good day.

I have integrated JWplaye in a website for video and audio streaming. 
Is there a way to prevent the snipping of ts segments of video which is being played in JWplayer? I have implemented url signing but it's still happening. (I think url signing is only for download prevention of video). 
In following question it is mentioned that we can encrypt video using key and decrepit it in media player it this possible in JWplayer?
[Prevent jwplayer video to download from chrome mobile browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44182696/prevent-jwplayer-video-to-download-from-chrome-mobile-browser)

Also it mentions DRM which is built in in player as per their specification. 
Is their a way to turn it on in JWplayer
Also please refer to following image in which i have downloaded the content using a chrome extension stream video downloaded this is what i'm trying to prevent ultimately.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XcTWi.jpg 
any help on the topic is appreciated any link to article or jwplayer tutorial etc.
I am trying to find solution for this but don't know key words to google or where to start.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can’t prevent people from download the media (how would jwplayer download it, if downloading is disabled). DRM doesn’t need to be “turned on” in the player. If the files are encrypted using cenc, As for google terms, DRM, EME, widevine.